# Partitioning a table in BigQuery by file

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition

I would like to create a table that is partitioned based on the filename. For example, let's say I have a thousand sales file, one for each date such as:

- `Files/Sales_2014-01-01.csv`, `Files/Sales_2014-01-02.csv`, ...

I would like to partition the table based on the filename (which is essentially the date). Is there a way to do this in BQ? For example, I want to do a load job similar to the following (in pseudocode):

```
bq load gs://Files/Sales*.csv PARTITION BY filename
```

What would be the closest thing I could do to that?

Comment: If we look here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables  we see the discussion on partitioned tables.  What is "inside" the files?  Does each file contain records where each record has a field which is the sales date?  In which case, won't that mean that the table will be partitioned if you just load it?

Comment: @Kolban ha, yes of course it would. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a TIMESTAMP, DATE, or DATETIME column in a table, first create a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) by using the [Time-unit column partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#date_timestamp_partitioned_tables). When you load data to the table, BigQuery automatically puts the data into the correct partitions, based on the values in the column. To [create an empty partitioned table for time-unit column-partitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table) using bq CLI, please refer to the below command:

```
  bq mk -t \
  --schema 'ts:DATE,qtr:STRING,sales:FLOAT' \
  --time_partitioning_field ts \
  --time_partitioning_type DAILY \
  mydataset.mytable
```

Then load all your sales files into that Time-unit column partitioning table. It will automatically put the data into the correct partition. The following command loads data from multiple files in gs://mybucket/ into a table named mytable in mydataset. The schema would be auto detected. Please refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) for more information.

```
  bq load \
  --autodetect \
  --source_format=CSV \
  mydataset.mytable \
  gs://mybucket/mydata*.csv
```